# How do I query on my has_many association's table's parameter?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
Category 
String id; 
String name; 
boolean enabled;

Product 
String id; 
String name; 
boolean enabled; 
int categoryId;
```

I need to search for all of the `enabled` categories that actually have `products` and those `products` should have `enabled` set to `true`.

I am not really that adept at SQL queries so could someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: I could easily do this in Rails using includes(:products).where('products.enabled = ? AND categories.enabled = ?', true, true) but how would I do it using RAW SQL?

Comment: Do you also want to get the associated product data?

Comment: No I don't I just want the list of categories :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
SELECT Category.* FROM Category   
INNER JOIN Product ON Category.id=Product.categoryId  
 WHERE  Category.enabled = 1 AND Product.enabled=1
 GROUP BY Category.id
```

I am not sure about the boolean values representation in your DB, assuming it is 1/0

Comment: Why the `RIGHT JOIN`? Any `NULL` categories will be filtered out by the `WHERE` condition anyway.